# how to expand dxTreeview by page load

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, devextreme

When page load, how to expand child nodes in devExtreme dxTreeview control by default. Please give some suggestions or examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger a click on each trigger:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    $( '.dx-treeview-toggle-item-visibility' ).each( function(){
        $( this ).click();
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It's work fine on single level expanded tree node. But i need nested tree expanded (2 or 3 level).

Comment: do you have a fiddle for me, so i can try around? I think my solution just needs a little addition, but I don't know what

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive approach:

```
// Declare a function
var clickRecursive = function ($elements, selector) {
  // Exit recursion
  if ($elements.length === 0) return;

  $elements.each(function(){
    // First, click all elements
    $(this).click();

    // Then click children
    clickRecursive($(this).find(selector), selector);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var toggleSelector = '.dx-treeview-toggle-item-visibility';
  clickRecursive($(toggleSelector), toggleSelector);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expandedExpr` option. It specifies the name of the data source item field whose value defines whether or not the corresponding node is expanded. For example, you could init dxTreeView something like this:

```
$("#your-selector").dxTreeView({
   dataSource: [
        id: 1, text: 'Item 1', expanded: true, items: [
            id: 2, text: 'Subitem 1', expanded: true, items: [
              //...
            ]
        ]
   ]
});
```

Also you can use `expandItem(itemElement)` method to expand some particular node.

See more information here http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView